# Git: cannot push newly cloned repos

Tags: git, ssh, rsync, gitolite, git-flow

I have a new desktop running Ubuntu. I have rsynced a bunch of git repos from my previous computer to my new one. I can push and pull with these all with no problem. However, if I do a `git clone` on a new repository (we use gitolite and gitflow), any `git push` hangs. Even if I can successfully push an rsynced project, doing a `git clone` of the project from gitolite is successful but results in a project I cannot push. The `.git/config` files are identical.

My computer:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ovid-desktop 3.0.0-16-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 14 12:48:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Git push output (or [read the strace output](https://gist.github.com/2035495)):

```
GIT_TRACE=1 git push -vv origin users/ovid
trace: built-in: git 'push' '-vv' 'origin' 'users/ovid'
Pushing to gitolite:libs/perl/ThirdParty-Sync
trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'gitolite' 'git-receive-pack '\''libs/perl/ThirdParty-Sync'\'''
trace: run_command: 'pack-objects' '--all-progress-implied' '--revs' '--stdout' '--thin' '--delta-base-offset' '--progress'
trace: exec: 'git' 'pack-objects' '--all-progress-implied' '--revs' '--stdout' '--thin' '--delta-base-offset' '--progress'
trace: built-in: git 'pack-objects' '--all-progress-implied' '--revs' '--stdout' '--thin' '--delta-base-offset' '--progress'
Counting objects: 53, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (21/21), done.
Writing objects: 100% (28/28), 2.59 KiB, done.
Total 28 (delta 13), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

And it hangs forever after the `Total 28 (delta...` line.

A successful push from the same project, but from the rsynced directory, looks like this:

```
To gitolite:libs/perl/ThirdParty-Sync                                                                                                                 
   8c056a5..0321b35  users/ovid -> users/ovid
```

The only symptom (red herring?) I can think of which might be related is this:

```
$ ssh gitolite
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
```

I have to add a -T to make that work.

Again, I can successfully push if I'm in the rsynced `ThirdPart-Sync` directory. It's only if I try to clone that project again from out gitolite server that it fails.

**Update**: Turns out it doesn't hang forever. After quite a while, I get the following after the `Total 28` line.

```
Write failed: Broken pipe
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

**Update** Running strace doesn't tell me what's going on. On a repo I cannot push:

```
wait4(4122, Counting objects: 53, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Writing objects: 100% (28/28), 11.62 KiB, done.
    Total 28 (delta 3), reused 28 (delta 3)
[{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 4122
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
read(3,
```

Running a strace on a repo I *can* push gives me this from approximately the same spot:

```
write(9, "^0321b3501969dead78a83a0d3234724"..., 42) = 42
write(9, "b9cbbc6cc37100baf706746205e7a4c4"..., 41) = 41
close(9)                                = 0
wait4(4632, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 4632
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
read(6, "000e", 4)                      = 4
read(6, "unpack ok\n", 10)              = 10
read(6, "001d", 4)                      = 4
read(6, "ok refs/heads/users/ovid\n", 25) = 25
read(6, "0000", 4)                      = 4
futex(0x7f8a49c619d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 4631, NULL) = 0
```

Comment: I always have `PTY allocation request failed on channel 0`: the force-command directive in your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` includes a `no-tty`

Comment: VonC: we removed the no-pty and it still fails. Looks like a red herring.

Comment: do you mean that it has no bearing on your current freezed push?

Comment: VonC: that is correct. It fixed the ssh problem (thank you!) but does not fix the git problem.

Comment: Ok. I am currently in the process of setting up a gitolite, and I haven't experienced your issue. Can you: create a new repo through a new declaration in your `gitolite-admin/conf/gitolite.conf` file? (By the way, can you clone, and then push back *that* repo? The `gitolite-admin`one?), try to clone that new (empty) repo, add some commit and push back?

Comment: VonC: After much hell, I switched from an dsa ssh key to an rsa ssh key and everything started working.

Comment: rsa, right. I never tried dsa keys before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP Ovid stated in the comment

> VonC: After much hell, I **switched from an dsa ssh key to an `rsa` ssh key** and everything started working.

The Gitolite documentation "[how gitolite uses ssh](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/gl_ssh.html)" only mentions [rsa keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29).
So it seems safe to keep using that particular kind of key.

The check utility (packaged with gitoite) [**`sshkeys-lint`**](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/src/sshkeys-lint#L127) only parse for rsa (or dss)

Answer (score 1):

Can you push *any* repos to Gitolite?  Or just ones you didn't rsync over?

What about your ~/.gitconfig?

If I were in your situation, I would try two things:

- strace to figure out what git-push/ssh are waiting on.
- Use the ControlMaster/ControlPath SSH in ~/.ssh/config to create a shared SSH connection, and try to push after running ssh -T gitolite.

Comment: I can push all repos I rsynced over. I cannot push any that I clone directly on this box.

My ~/.gitconfg is pretty bog-standard. It sets colors, my username/email and a couple of aliases, none of which conflict. I'll try the strace.

Comment: I've updated my query with some truncated strace information, or you could see the full failed strace git push at https://gist.github.com/2035495

Answer (score 1):

Try following steps:

```
   $git pull
   $git push origin branch
```

Comment: Already tried. Switching from a dsa to rsa public ssh key fixed it. No idea why.

Answer (score 0):

try comparing the config in the new repos. The defaults change between git versions.